# Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB. Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running? When lifting sails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

Hi guys im  receiving an error

Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB. Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running? Error details: { [MongoError: failed to connect to server on first connect] name: 'MongoError', message: 'failed to connect to server on first connect' }

I'm using a previous version of Sails since that its the version that they are currently using

Sails ~0.12.4
nodejs -v 4.2.6
npm -v 3.5.2

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load! 
error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?

Error details:{ [MongoError: failed to connect to server [192.168.2.45:27017] on first connect] name: 'MongoError',
failed to connect to server [192.168.2.45:27017] on first connect]
name: 'MongoError', message: 'failed to connect to server [192.168.2.45:27017] on first connect' }
```

My config/connection.js looks like this

```
module.exports.connections = {
 localDiskDb: {
adapter: 'sails-disk'
},
mongodbServer: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: '192.168.2.45',
port: 27017,
user      : 'dbAdmin',
password  : 'hiveslab',
database: 'sauce_db'
},
};
```

I'm stuck on this for a day and I'm pretty much of a newbie here. Hopefully you guys can lead me to the right resolution. Thank you in advance have a good day.

Comment: Can you check that Mongodb is running in your Machine or the Machine which you are trying to connect ,

Comment: Yes, mongodb is running on my virtual machine. I use vagrant to set up a virtual machine and install mongodb on it. when i run mongo it does respond.

Comment: Check the insallation , you should test your mongod is running in your machine before connect to ti , try with mongod , or capture the output to see the error !

Comment: Hi guys, it manage to automatically work now after i close my laptop and comeback in the office. Its working fine now and Sails is lifting up now. I think a restart of the server will help others solve their issue if they encounter this. Thanks for helping.